# Android L Youtube API - IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit

Tags: android, youtube, android-service, android-youtube-api

I know that on L I can only bind services that are declared explicit. In my app I'm currently using Youtube API and when running on devices with L I always get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
```

How can I fix the problem make Youtube API works also on L ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is available a new version of the Youtube API (1.2.1) that fixes this issue. It can be downloaded from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/).

If you need to use the old version for some reason keep reading:

There is a bug in the Youtube API v1.0.0 in Lollipop. More info [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1247) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6739).

As a workaround you can use **android:targetSdkVersion="19" in the manifest** while **maintaining API 21 as build target** (You still will be able to make use of the Lollipop API in your project).

Comment: It is available a new version of the Youtube API (1.2.1) that fixes this issue.

Comment: kept crashing at the developer key. this helped.

Answer (score 9):

***UPDATE*** 
The new android youtube SDK has been released! No more implicit intent problem:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATE: 2018.12.06 :: Link below no longer works ** 
This worked for me with the billing API.

http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/10/android-l-api-21-javalangillegalargumen.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get the intent that cause the error using the Youtube api. Is there a way to modify a class inside the .jar file?

Comment: I suspect it would be a bit difficult. Your best bet is to contact the author of the .jar, if possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the old Youtube Api with **Latest Youtube Api Version**